# Getting list-display to show ManyToManyField in an organized format Django

Tags: python, django, format

I have the code:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', null =True)

    def get_products(self):
        return "\n".join([p.products for p in self.product.all()])

class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=256, null =True)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.products
```

in views.py:

```
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   fields = ['product']
   list_display = ('get_products')
```

Which gives me this: 
[image]
However, the problem is the format is very uglyish. How can I get it like this:

[image]

Comment: did you try `return "<br />".join([p.products for p in self.product.all()])` ?

Comment: hmm I just tried "<BR> </BR>". join([p.products for p in self.product.all()]) but nothing worked

Comment: `<br></br>` is not a valid HTML tag

Comment: Do I have to somehow allow an html tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal):

```
 class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('get_products')
     filter_vertical = ['product']
```

Or you can use an [`inline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models):

```
class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
     model = Product

 class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     inlines = (ProductInline,)
```

Comment: The filter_vertical only does a filter for the screen with the first image. I want the second image's display.